# How to use dual monitors with Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, multiple-monitors

I've set up Hyper-V on my Windows 10 pro Laptop (Dell XPS 15 9650), guest OS is also Windows 10 pro.

The host os is using an external display (set to extend).

When I start the VM from Hyper-V manager it asks me if I want to use all the monitors so I click yes. It doesn't end up using the external monitor, but rather uses a very high resolution on the laptop internal display.

I've enabled incoming remote desktop connections on the guest OS and I can RDP from the host OS into the guest OS and dual screens work.

Using RDP manually seems kind of clunky and not properly integrated. Shouldnt it "just work" from the Hyper-V manager? If so, how do I make it work? Do I need to do something with  RemoteFx?

Or is there another virtuslization solution that might fit my needs better?

Comment: It’s RDP either way. While initiating a connection manually may seem tedious, it actually offers the complete RDP feature set. Every virtualization software *but* Hyper-V has proper support for just about everything. ;)

Comment: Have you looked at Hyper-V enhanced session mode? https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2013/12/05/overview-client-hyper-v-enhanced-session-mode-in-windows-8-1/ - I believe that this is something that you have to enable both on the Hyper-V server (in Hyper-V settings) as well as in each VM settings (what they show in the article). Then, you should be able to choose to span multiple monitors.

Comment: And this is why I use Virtual Box.  Not helpful, I know, but it's frustrating to be locked into Hyper-V if I want to use Docker for Desktop.